# Using enumerate in Python to iterate up to len(list) - 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, enumeration

If I have a list

```
A = [5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 6, 19, 2, 6]
```

I can loop through all the elements but the last, using this code:

```
for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    pass
```

Can I use `enumerate()` in this loop to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slice the list you provide to `enumerate` to achieve a similar effect:

```
for i, item in enumerate(A[:-1]):
    print(item, end=' ')
```

touches all, but the last, elements of the list `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course:

```
for i, item in enumerate(A[:-1]):
    pass
```

Comment: It's not the same thing.

Comment: i might misunderstand the question. How is it different?

Comment: OP wants everything minus last element

Comment: ah yes :-) I didn't even notice